False Positive Rates at a fixed False Negative Rate
When reporting False Positive Rates (FPRs) at a fixed False Negative Rate (FNR), does the choice of threshold still matter for comparison purposes, or is it sufficient to compare FPRs directly since the FNR is fixed?
Also any references will be appreciated

Varying the threshold will usually also change the FNR, so I am a little unclear what you mean by "does the choice of threshold matter if the FNR is fixed" - a fixed FNR usually implies a fixed threshold. Can you please clarify?
